# Program finished with exit code 10

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I am trying to implement copy constructor.
I hope I had followed the correct syntax of copy constructor.
But whenever I compile my code it'll finish without any errors but at run time it says "Program finished with exit code 10".
I'm working in Clion IDE. When I tried in Mac terminal it showed "Bus error: 10"

I could figure out that copy constructor is causing this problem.
I tried by Commenting it and running the program, it worked fine, when I uncomment it the above problem is caused.

Please help me figure out where I went wrong.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
public:
    Person ();
    Person (char *, int age = 18);
    Person (const Person &p);
    void output ();
};

Person ::Person() {
    name = new char[20]();
    age = 0;
}

Person ::Person(char *str, int age) {
    name = new char[50]();
    strcpy(name, str);
    this->age = age;
}

Person ::Person(const Person &p) {
    strcpy(name, p.name);
    age = p.age;
}

void Person ::output() {
    cout << "\nName = " << name;
    cout << "\nAge = " << age << endl;
    cout <<"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

int main () {
    Person p1;
    Person p2("Name");
    Person p3 ("Name", 20);
    Person p4 = p2;

    cout << "\nThe Output of the Object Called by Default Constructor\n\n";
    p1.output();
    cout << "\nThe Output of the Object Called by Parameterised Constructor with Default Argument\n\n";
    p2.output();
    cout << "\nThe Output of the Object Called by Parameterised Constructor Overriding Default Argument \n\n";
    p3.output();
    cout << "\nThe Output of the Object Called by Copy Constructor (Copying p2 Object that is the second output)\n\n";
    p4.output();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Most probably your program crashes here: `strcpy(name, p.name);` You allocated size for `name` are inconsistent. Just use `std::string` instea of `char*`.

Comment: Thanks this helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were is you **allocation**?
`Person ::Person(const Person &p) {
    strcpy(name, p.name);
    age = p.age;
}`

You should allocate memory for your member `name` the size of `strlen(p.name)+1` bytes before copying data to it.

Comment: Take care of memory leaks.

Comment: This is very true. Destructor must free any dynamic memory owned by this class.

Comment: @PazO I meant your proposal for fixing the copy constructor.

Comment: Copy constructor by itself cannot create any memory leak. It is called before object was ever constructed, thus your member 'name' could not have be previously allocated. The only location to protect against memory loss are in assignment operator (=), in any manually asignment operator (SetXxx) and in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

If I am going to answer your Question from only the **title** of your question, the answer will be quite simple.

> But **firstly** Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible
>   Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because it helps other to **understand** and **examin** your code.

`exit()` is a termination built-in function, uesed to terminate programm normally.

and it takes one parameter called `Status code`. which indicate also 2 simple states.

1. If it is 0 or `EXIT_SUCCESS` ([macro](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/importance-of-macros-in-c/)), it indicates **success**, `exit(0)` or `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`.
2. If it is `EXIT_FAILURE`, it indicates **failure**, `exit(1)` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

so for any other value of `exit(10)`, or `exit(1)` it indicates error.

To learn more about exit() see here:

- [exit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) - cpluscplus
- [exit() vs _Exit() in C and C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exit-vs-_exit-c-cpp/) - GeaksforGeaks
- [exit(), abort() and assert()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-exit-abort-and-assert/) - GeaksforGeaks

> Now from your code it shows up that you are new with **`pointers`**, so It
>   will be very good for you to read this article because it will give
>   you Guideline rules of how to use pointers in a right way to prevent `out of
>   memory` and `memory leaks` and `Segfault` errors.
>
> **[C++ Core Guidelines: Rules to Resource Management](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-to-resource-management)**